# How to run live adMob ads instead of test ads in ios Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, admob

I'm close to pushing my app to the app store and before I do I would like to make sure my adMob Banner will eventually show actual ads.  How do I ensure it will show live ads?  Currently my code looks like this.....

```
bannerView.adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-***********/**************"
            bannerView.rootViewController = self
            bannerView.delegate = self

            let request = GADRequest()
            request.testDevices = [kGADSimulatorID]
            bannerView.loadRequest(request)
            bannerView.center = adCell.contentView.center
            adCell.addSubview(bannerView)
```

Comment: Are you testing in the simulator?

Comment: @Nik Yes, I'm successfully showing test ads in the Simulator.  I want to make sure live ones show in actual live app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To not show test ads in the simulator, simply remove/comment out the line:

```
request.testDevices = [kGADSimulatorID]
```

This line tells AdMob to show test ads when run in the simulator (and any other device identifiers put in the array). If you were to test it on a real device right now, you would see normal ads. This line of code doesn't even need to be removed for real ads to show on a real device because you're not telling it to show test ads on any specific devices anyway (just the simulator).

### Note

Clicking your own ads can get your account banned from AdMob, so be extremely careful when testing with real ads.